# Mongoose findOne returns null on type mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Model that contains a foreign key **eid** of type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. Whenever I try to filter records using that particular column i get a null result yet the record exists.
Here is the schema.

```
const attendanceSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    eid: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Employee",
      required: true,
    },
    month: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paidAmount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    yearMonth: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

here is the query

```
  const attendance = await Attendance.findOne({
      eid:req.body.eid,
    });
```

I also tried casting eid from req.body to `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

```
 const attendance = await Attendance.findOne({
      eid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.eid),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I Found out that I used `req.body.eid` rather than `req.body.employeeId`.